# Testing class (JAVA)

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm learning Java currently. I have just learned the basics about unit testing, and etc. What is the main purpose for unit testing?

Comment: www.google.com => purpose unit testing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of unit testing is to ensure that units of your code work as they are supposed to.  As an example, if you have a method that should always return 1 you test it with.

```
interface One {
  int alwaysOne();
}

class OneTest {
   One one = new OneImpl(); //You can implement OneImpl as an exercise
   @Test
   public void testAlwaysOne() {
     assertEquals("Should ALWAYS return 1", 1, one.alwaysOne());
   }
 }
```

Now you run your test and you get a green light.  When your project moves further and all around the code you can work on the assumption that `alwaysOne()` behaves in a specific way.  If one day another developer decides to change OneImpl he will run the tests an get a failure and thus know he broke something.

I suggest you read some tutorial on junit ([Lars Vogel's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html#junit_intro) is not bad)

Answer (score 3):

to ensure the code you wrote does what you expected it to do

Comment: That's about as compact as it gets.

Comment: LOL +1 for ultimate one liner :)